# SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0 when ajax callback json

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

From the network debugger, in php file, it shows {message: "Success", data: {Name: "admin"}}". However, when ajax callback, it fails.  Can anyone help fix these problem that troubles me a long time. Thank you very much.

There is the errors message generated by ajax.

- OK
- parsererror
- SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0

Ps: In MYSQL database, Username & Password are varchar(20)

Html:

```
 function User_Login(){
     var Username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
     var Password = document.getElementById("Password").value;



     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'Api_Login.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {Username : Username , Password : Password},
         //call back method
         success:  function(returnData){
             JSON.parse(returnData.message);
             console.log(returnData);
             if  (returnData.message ==='Success') {
                 window.location="homepage/index.html";
             } else {
                 window.alert("No such account or wrong password");
             }
         },
         error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
             console.log(xhr.statusText);
             console.log(textStatus);
             console.log(error);

         }
     });

 }
```

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT Name
            FROM `$tbName`
            WHERE Name = '$userID'
            AND Password = '$UserPassword' ";



$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($data){

    echo json_encode(
        array("message" =>  "Success", "data" => $data));

}else {
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "Fail"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` function returns `JSON` object  `{message: "Success", data: {Name: "admin"}}`we can not call `JSON.parse()` on `JSON` object.

Just remove the line `JSON.parse(returnData.message);` from your code and it is working fine.

Comment: jQuery.ajax does not always callback success with JS Object, it depends on many factors.

Answer (score 0):

Setting **datatype** as json will force jQuery to convert response to JS Object. It will throw error if server has responded back with invalid json.

Again, the **returnData** will be a JS object, you don't need to run `JSON.parse` on it.
Try with this.

```
success:  function(returnData){
     console.log(returnData);
     if  (returnData.message ==='Success') {
         window.location="homepage/index.html";
     } else {
         window.alert("No such account or wrong password");
     }
}
```

You can make sure what your server is responding by removing setting line

```
dataType: 'json',
```

See what id logged in console.

Comment: What is logged in console, or first try to remove datatype setting

Comment: same three problem mentioned above ... when i remove datatype , same problem

Comment: set dataType to text, sometime mime can be a issue

Comment: when i add "text", the message is gone. but    console.log(returnData.message);  it return undefined

Comment: offcourse, it will return undefined, because this time returnData is simple string object. why don't to try logging just returnData.